# Reloading UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I've read some of the other posts but haven't found the right solution that seems to work in my case. I've got a UITableViewController class that is instantiated from the Main App Delegate and it controls other views that get pushed into the UINavigationController instance created from the App Delegate.

On the UINavigationToolBar I have a UISegmentedControl button that is split in two pieces, Factory Loads and User Loads. I have an action method attached to the SegmentedControl to detect when the button is pressed and that method is inside the UIViewController Class. My goal is to have the view reload with the contents of a new dictionary that is constructed from a plist file in the app bundle. I have the dictionary loaded, and the keys to be displayed set up in the respective data formats, but when I try to reload the UITableView, it crashes.

This is the last code I tried to get to work inside my action method, but it still doesn't function as intended.

```
- (void) action:(id)sender {

UISegmentedControl *segment = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
if ([segment selectedSegmentIndex] == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"User Load Selected");

    NSString *userLoadFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UserLoads" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *userLoadDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:userLoadFilePath];
    NSArray *allKeys = [userLoadDictionary allKeys];
    keys = allKeys;
    dictionary = userLoadDictionary;

    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

else if ([segment selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Factory Load Selected");

    NSString *factoryLoadFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AlliantPowder" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *factoryLoadDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:factoryLoadFilePath];
    NSArray *allKeys = [factoryLoadDictionary allKeys];
    keys = allKeys;

    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
}
```

I'm calling `[[self tableView] reloadData]` in an attempt to retrieve the actual table contained within the UIViewController to try to get the table to reload, but no luck. Any help is appreciated, and if more code is needed please ask. Thanks!

Andrew

------- Edit -----------
Here is the new code in reference to Chip's ideas. The issue is still not resolved and the app still crashes.

```
- (void) action:(id)sender {

// Create an instance of UISegmentedControl and set it as the sending event.
UISegmentedControl *segment = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;

// Detect which button was pressed and load a new dictionary appropriately
// Checking if userLoads was selected
if ([segment selectedSegmentIndex] == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"User Load Selected");

    keys = userKeys;
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

// Checking if factoryLoads was selected
else if ([segment selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Factory Load Selected");

    keys = [dictionary allKeys];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];

}

[segment release];
}
```

Comment: Where are you implementing `- (void) action:(id)sender {`?

Comment: The implementation of the action method is in the class RootViewController.m, which is where the UISegmentedController is also created and functioning. This class is a UITableViewController which extends the `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>` classes as well and has the respected methods for creating its UITableView. This is why I call `[[self tableView] reloadData]`. I'm thinking I can extract the tableView and then reload it with the new array of keys. The cell creation is simple and just sets the title based on the value in the array.

Comment: You probably should be assigning to properties instead of ivars; `-[NSDictionary allKeys]` is probably autoreleased and thus causing your crash (and there are a pile of leaks too).

Comment: Ya I know I have lots of leaks, I'm mostly concerned with getting the code operational than getting optimized. The ` keys` is a property, but `allkeys` is just a local variable to be able to stash it and get it out of the dictionary. I'm going to try out the answer below by Chip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pre-load the dictionaries and hold them as ivars in the controller class.

I am betting that the loading of the dictionary contents is not complete, so you are in effect calling reloadData while the data is changing which is causing your crash.

Also, the read is an expensive option and you are loading each time the segementControl changes state.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that approach and load the dictionary where I load the original when the app launches. I'll try to keep up with my memory leaks too. Like I said in the above comment, I'm more focusses on making functional code than optimized code at this moment in time. Thanks!

Comment: So I redid the code as you suggested to add ivars and set them up earlier in the application so that way we can switch the keys around to display the new content. Using `NSLog()` I've been able to verify it's loading the data from the file, but it still crashes when attempting to reload the `UITableView`. I've updated the post to add the new code.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace on your crash and/or the code in your method the crash is occurring in (i.e. is it in your action method or in the "cellForIndexPath..." method?)

Comment: I'm re-doing a lot of the code at this point, i'll post updates when I get stuck. Thanks!